# How to properly align Font Awesome symbols on Highcharts scatter plots?

Tags: highcharts, font-awesome, scatter-plot

Using the Highcharts [example posted here](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/2A7Zf/) how can you ensure that the Font Awesome icons will be positioned exactly in the middle of the data point like the native symbols/markers are?  It gets called like this in the data series and uses the "plugin" that is found in that same Fiddle:

```
marker: {
    symbol: 'text:\uf183' // fa-male
}
```

Using that example, if you toggle the series on/off a couple of times or zoom in/out the icons are no longer visually accurate, often displaying above the actual coordinate.  In the image below you'd believe that data point had a value >50 based on where the icon is.

[image: Icons are off-center]

Their [SVGRenderer example here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/) doesn't seem to be effected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like problem with re-rendering icons later - height of the marker isn't considered. I suggest to change a bit logic for rendering icon:

```
        var text = symbol.split(':')[1],
            svgElem = this.text(text, x, y)
            .attr({
                translateY: h, // translate marker
                translateX: -1
            })
            .css({
                fontFamily: 'FontAwesome',
                fontSize: h * 2
            });
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2A7Zf/29/

Comment: This worked great -- thank you!  It also had the added benefit of fixing an additional problem I was experiencing where exactly one of the data series would display slightly too low each time until you toggled it on/off.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the markers XL-sized (i.e larger radius) for a custom chart (e.g. a Yes/No prevalence chart using the x and check icons, circle empty for the less prevalent one and circle filled for the more prevalent one and data labels showing counts/%s), then I'd recommend this tweak to center the symbols:

```
          translateX:  -w/2 + options.radius/4 - 3
```